# How to wrap Long Text in data-column of table in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table which is responsive through custom CSS when I use an attribute

`<td data-column="Column Name or Long Text"></td>`

The large text in data-column not wrapped in the table. It goes outside the table.

```
        .table_card_view { border-collapse: collapse; }

        @media only screen and (max-width:768px) and (min-width:200px)  {
          .table_card_view, .table_card_view thead, .table_card_view tbody, .table_card_view th, .table_card_view td, .table_card_view tr 
          { display: block; }  
          
          .table_card_view thead tr { position: absolute; top: -9999px; left: -9999px; }
          
         .table_card_view tr 
          { border: 1px solid #ccc; margin-top: 4%; border-radius:7px; }
          
        .table_card_view td {
          border: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #eee;position: relative; padding-left: 50%; 
         }

        .table_card_view td:before { 
            top: 6px; left: 6px; width: 45%;padding-right: 10px;  white-space: nowrap; content: attr(data-column); color: #000; font-weight: bold;
         }
      }
    
     <body>     
        <table class="table table-striped table_card_view">    
            <thead><tr>
                  <th> Date and Time </th>
                  <th> 
                     No. of Company 1 Users Processed in Company 2 
                  </th>
                  <th> 
                     No. of Company 2 Tickets Processed in Company 2 
                  </th>     
                  <th> Any Error ? </th>
               </tr> </thead>
                          
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td data-column="Date and Time"> 23 July 2019 </td>
                  <td data-column="No. of Company 1 Users Processed in Company 2">
                  1 </td>
                  <td data-column="No. of Company 1 Tickets Processed in Company 2">  
                  2 </td>
                  <td data-column="Any Sync Error ?"> 0 </td>
               </tr></tbody>

         </table>
       </body>
```

I want large text used in data-column="", not goes outside the table.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `word-break` css property

```
   th, td {
        word-break: break-word;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Vikas, thanks for the help but I already tried this but this CSS property does not work on data column's text attribute.

Answer (score 0):

td
{

line-break: anywhere;
white-space: pre-line;

}

use this property. i hope this will work

Comment: Hi @Raja Usman, thanks for the help but this CSS property does not work on data column's text attribute.

Comment: why you can't use data-label in td . box sizing is worked on data-label

Comment: I used data-label now, but when I check on 360 x 640 view it goes outside.

Comment: gives td ( width:100%; display:block; padding:10px) try this

Comment: Hi, I attached the screenshot, this is how the design display in mobile view. The above properties that answered are only work on inside the table data means <td>Data</td>. Not on data-column.